# Edit grass block

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-addons

Using add-ons, how do I edit the texture of a grass block? Do I use `grass.png`? Do I use `grass_carried.png`? Are either of those the answer? I see that in the default textures, `grass.png` is gray and `grass_carried.png` is green.

Comment: Note that it's not called `grass.png`, but `grass.tga`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grass.tga` is the block used for when it is placed.

`grass_carried.png` is used for certain textures that don't define a biome type, like in menus (i.e. the application of addons in the behavior/resource pack menu or inventory).

Whenever there is a texture that has a `_carried.png` variant, the carried one is for non-placement uses.